# Multiple Django Instances on one AppEngine Server

Tags: django, google-app-engine

For our project we host both the website and the actual webapp on one AppEngine instance. I separated them both nicely in different projects, but they all share the same settings file. It's becoming more and more clear to me that these should actually be independent django instances as they use different settings for middleware, template loaders, etc.

So I tried running two django instances on the same server (different handlers), but because django uses global variables for caching all over the place, which the AppEngine runtime caches between requests, I couldn't get this to work reliably. Did anyone successfully do this before?

Answer (score 1):

Since you can run [multiple app versions simultaneously](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/06/10-things-you-probably-didnt-know-about.html), I would put this independent django instances in different app versions.